# Login using url with username and password in android mobile app

Tags: android, rest, web-services, authentication

I am working on android mobile application for website I have a url username and password.I need to login through app.How it should be done? Do I need to use any library for authentication.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: For making any REST API call you need to add library like OkHttp, retrofit in your project.

Comment: or you have use javascript interface using webview

Answer (score 0):

Network requests with Android should be done with a library, such as Retrofit or Volley. If you are new to Android and/or looking for a quick solution to your login, I suggest trying Volley as it takes less experience to set up. Here is a good resource to learn about [Volley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2xtLqP8dSQ).

Another good option, and the most widely adopted solution as of current is Retrofit. If you are doing anything more than a few simple network calls in your app, I strongly suggest learning about [Retrofit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGvDUlfk7Y). It takes a bit more Android knowledge in my opinion, but it is a more elegant solution and worth the learning.

You will have to learn to make a POST request to your API using either of these libraries, passing in the username and password as parameters or in the request body. The API will likely return a token for authentication in the response body. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to implement some rest api libraries.

```
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Then after create class ApiClient.. in this class write below code in it

```
public class ApiClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();



    return retrofit;
}}
```

Now create Interface ApiInterface and write below code in it..

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login/")
Call<Your Pojo Class> loginuser(@Field("method") String method, @Field("login_name") 
   String loginname,@Field("password") String password);}
```

In your MainActivity Write belowe code..

```
APIInterface apiInterface;
apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
Call<EarnAmount> call = apiInterface.loginuser("loginuser", loginid,password);



call.enqueue(new Callback<Your Pojo>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<Your Pojo> call, Response<Your Pojo> response) {
                     //you will get some response
                     //you can handle response from here

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<Your Pojo> call, Throwable t) {
                        //check internet connection or something went wrong
                                }
                                });    }
```